# change time zone offset without changing timezone id in linux RHEL

Tags: linux, date, time-zone, rhel-6

My current timezone is 'Africa/Khartoum' which is GMT+3:00, as per government desiccation it's going to be GMT+2:00 starting from 1st Nov. I know I can change my current date to be an hour earlier but still when I print the timezone info I get 'GMT+3:00' how can I change the timezone offset without the need to set the date.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a timezone file.

See [`man tzfile`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/tzfile) for the file contents and [`man zic`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/zic) for a way to generate one, even if a quick-and-dirty way is to copy some TZ file from a city on GMT+2 and the same DST settings.

On my current Linux, `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Khartoum` is a soft link to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Juba` so you will end up having two different files.